# Python dictionary: creating new dictionary based on values of the first

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```
d1 = {'user1': 5, 'user2': 50, 'user3': 75, 'user4': 100}^M
```

And another dictionary like so:

```
d2 = {5: 1, 50: 2, 75: 3, 100: 4}
```

How would I create a third dictionary like this?

```
d1 = {'user1': 1, 'user2': 2, 'user3': 3, 'user4': 4}^M
```

(Not manually of course, since the dictionaries are just simple examples).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dict` comprehension for this by using the value from the first dictionary as a key into the second

```
>>> d1 = {'user1': 5, 'user2': 50, 'user3': 75, 'user4': 100}
>>> d2 = {5: 1, 50: 2, 75: 3, 100: 4}
>>> {key:d2[value] for key, value in d1.items()}
{'user1': 1, 'user2': 2, 'user3': 3, 'user4': 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d1 = {'user1': 5, 'user2': 50, 'user3': 75, 'user4': 100}
d2 = {5: 1, 50: 2, 75: 3, 100: 4}
d3 = {a:d2[b] for a, b in d1.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'user1': 1, 'user2': 2, 'user3': 3, 'user4': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dict`

**Ex:**

```
d1 = {'user1': 5, 'user2': 50, 'user3': 75, 'user4': 100}
d2 = {5: 1, 50: 2, 75: 3, 100: 4}

print( dict((k,d2[v]) for k, v in d1.items() ) )
```

**Output:**

```
{'user4': 4, 'user2': 2, 'user3': 3, 'user1': 1}
```

Comment: i suggest add the output.. and add more details from your code !!